# Using boto3 with a threaded tkinter progressbar

Tags: python, tkinter, boto3

I am trying to construct a simple GUI for uploading some arbitrary file to S3 using boto3.

The main body of the app is:

```
import os
import boto3
from threading import Thread
import sys
import threading
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from tkinter import ttk


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xxxxxx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "xxxxxx"
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "eu-central-1"


bucket = 'bucket1'


filename = "example.png"

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("750x400")



button = tkinter.Button(root,text="Pstart_upload",command=AsyncUpload)
button.pack()
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal",
                                length=200, mode="determinate")
progress.pack()

progress["maximum"] = float(os.path.getsize(filename)) #filename is an arbitrary file 

root.mainloop()
```

The AsyncUpload is a threaded function (since tkinter runs on the main thread, it won't allow updating progress bar the callback), the classic example of the sys.stdout progress as well as the tqdm works flawlessly, however in this case the progress bar won't start and the program breaks after first three callbacks:

```
class ProgressPercentage(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
    def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
        print("first call") #to see the number of callbacks

        with self._lock:
            self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount
            percentage = (self._seen_so_far / self._size) * 100
            #try to set the value to the percentage
            progress["value"]=percentage
    
            
        
class AsyncUpload(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.upload_file(
                filename, bucket, "test1",
                Callback=ProgressPercentage(filename))
```

Any help or a possible workaround would be much appreciated since I am primarily a data scientist from a non python background. I am using this only as a prototype, but still I would not like my GUI to look like it gets broken/frozen each time I upload a file of >10mb (since it take around 3 secs to get "not responding" from windows)

Comment: please add the imports so that the code works:  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the imports, the code will not work without the boto3 keys however.